# Option strict On Vs. Checklistbox.items Vs. Late Binding

Tags: vb.net, checklistbox, option-strict

I have a databinded checklistbox:

```
    With Me.chkChaineSelected
            .DataSource = dtChainesTvRadio
            .DisplayMember = "Chaînes TV/RADIO"
    End With
```

To get the items checked, i use a loop:

```
Dim strSelectedLinkeChaine Aa String
For i As Integer = 0 To (chkChaineSelected.Items.Count - 1)
   If chkChaineSelected.GetItemChecked(i) Then
      strSelectedLinkeChaine = DirectCast(Me.chkChaineSelected.Items(i)("Chaînes TV/RADIO"), String)
   End If
Next
```

But this doesn't work with `Option Strict On`, the issue is *late binding* (BC30574) located on `Me.chkChaineSelected.Items(i)`

Comment: Syntax errors tend to generate confusing error messages.  It is not a multi-dimensional array, use plain Items(i)

Comment: Thanks but sorry but..how do i use plain items(i)? (i don't know what is plain Item?)

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I got "System.InvalidCastException : 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.String'.'"

Comment: DirectCast(Me.chkChaineSelected.Items(i), DataRowView)("Chaînes TV/RADIO")

Comment: .... and call `.ToString()`

Comment: Thank you Hans Passant and dr.null, ```DirectCast(Me.chkChaineSelected.Items(i), DataRowView)("Chaînes TV/RADIO").ToString``` works.